# Reading text + graphic (like lines) info from an existing pdf

Tags: pdf, text, line, graphic

I want to read an existing pdf & extract the text and graphics information. Within graphics, currently i just need the drawn lines. There are many vendor component for reading PDF text, but are there ones that can give graphics info too ? Though free/open-source is preferred, I'm ok to commercial ones too.

The requirement is:

For every page in PDF:

1. Reading text blocks
2. Getting to know the canvas co-ordinate of the text block (rectangle containing the block). Note, for text with higher font size, the rect size will change.
3. Lines - need collection of (x1,y1,x2,y2) for every line in a page in pdf

Thanks,
- Seeker

Answer (score 0):

This is my field, though the question is a bit old. Hopefully this still helps.

You leave some room for assumptions, so here are mine:

- you seek a script, rather than stand-alone software
- your object is archival

  1. you are running command-line scripts:
     Use this command line script, detailed at: http://stefaanlippens.net/extract-images-from-pdf-documents
  2. you are running server-side code using imagemagick or graphicsmagick functions:
     Something like "convert -background white -flatten test1.pdf test1.jpg" (imagemagick) will render the whole PDF page into a jpeg. If you want to then crop it to the image(s), then it depends upon the context of the project to determine the best script(s) to do that.

A rather complex question. If you wish to provide more details about the project, then I can provide some more guidance. Best of luck.

Comment: Similar question. I need to determine media boxes for fields in PDFs images. Trying to determine whether to parse the drawing commands or do layout analysis on the image itself. Do you have guidance here? Thx

Comment: That's a toughie, David. What's the purpose/output media? What parser do you have access to?

Comment: Small goal: some PDFs implement all fields but final signature and date fields, forcing user to print, sign, scan, and fax. We'd like to implement adding signature field with a tap, but we need a way to determine where the field appear. Large goal: Enable naive user who believes form image is actual PDF form by converting entire image to PDF with live fields. We've already decided working with an image is less of a nightmare than parsing draw commands. Currently using LxPDFParser (https://github.com/DeveloperLx/LxPDFParser).

Comment: Hmm. I would be tempted to look to your process to solve this problem: replacing PDF with traditional online forms and electronic signatures (or password/timestamp, etc.) would seem easier than the PDF approach.

If for whatever reason that is not possible, I would script the build of the PDF forms. This still doesn't solve the signature issue; but I can't say that's possible with PDF, if it still requires someone to sign with pen. Again, you would have to look to process to address disrupted user behaviour. (ie. Geoffrey Moore, Crossing the Chasm)